# Medal tags, bronze, silver, gold

Tags: feature-request, tags

The medal tags for Bioinfo SE are limited, i.e. tags that lead to bronze, silver and gold badges. In particular `phylogenetics` is a non-medal tag but this disapline is routinely represented in questions on the site.

How can this be rectified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The threshold on stackexchange to make a tag "medal eligible" is 100 questions. See [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) for more on that. Consequently, the way to resolve this is for more questions with that tag to be asked (or to edit it into previous questions that should have had it).

Comment: Thanks, now I've got it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it.

I've proposed a synonym between `phylogenetics` and `phylogeny` and `phylip` (a phylogenetics package). The phylogenetics/phylogeny synonym will help alot because manually editing these tags would be a bit messy.

On a lesser note I proposed synonym between `sequence-alignments` and `alignments`.